# What is the gravitational field lines pattern of a sphere of mass $m_1$ in an open ended box of mass $m_2$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, electrostatics, newtonian-gravity

[image]

This Quetsion is inspired by this Fig of a positively charged metal sphere in an earthed metal box:
  [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this Figure For point mass $m_1=1$, and box mass $m_2=3$, and box size $a$.

[image]

Comment: Can you give a little bit more information.What equations did you use?

Comment: I have used the Newton's law of gravitation (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_universal_gravitation), please, see the pdf version of my mathematica noetbook for drawing this figure: http://up.shamsipour-ac.ir/uploads/files/1395/ordibehesht/e_Gravitational-Line.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If you consider the case of a point charge (that we can take as positive) above a grounded conducting plane (not quite your problem) you can use the method of images to determine the electric field. In this case the field lines with be perpendicular at the surface of the plane, and this results in an induced surface charge which will be negative. I do not believe that the analogy you appear to be making is possible, since there is no such thing as negative mass (though have a look at [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/162629/is-the-method-of-images-applicable-to-gravity) where one of the answers seems to suggest that the method of images works in some cases).

Remember: you draw electric lines of force starting on positive charges and terminating on negative charges, can't do this for gravitational lines of force.